# Drag Select Objects in viewer Api?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

In Viewer API, is it possible to drag select objects? So that I can select multiple objects by dragging instead of ctrl + click every time?

Comment: Not doable by default unfortunately, you would need to implement that kind of feature yourself...

Comment: Can you give me any hint on developing this behavior?

Comment: There is no easy answer to that, you would need to convert 2D mouse position in 3D world, compute a rectangular volume and perform intersection detection with the model meshes in order to find out which meshes are inside/outside/intersected with the volume ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the process of implementing the window selection feature, as a code sample. Take a look at this [article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-i) for more details and stay tuned for the following ones ...

```
import Toolkit from 'Viewer.Toolkit'

export default class SelectSet {

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  constructor (viewer) {

    this.viewer = viewer

    this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene (
      'debug', this.lineMat)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Set model: required to compute the bounding boxes
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  async setModel (model) {

    this.model = model

    const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

    const rootId = instanceTree.getRootId()

    const bbox =
      await this.getComponentBoundingBox(
        model, rootId)

    this.boundingSphere = bbox.getBoundingSphere()

    const leafIds = await Toolkit.getLeafNodes (model)

    this.boundingBoxInfo = leafIds.map((dbId) => {

      const bbox = this.getLeafComponentBoundingBox(
        model, dbId)

      return {
        bbox,
        dbId
      }
    })

    console.log(this.boundingBoxInfo)
    console.log(model)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns bounding box as it appears in the viewer
  // (transformations could be applied)
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  getModifiedWorldBoundingBox (fragIds, fragList) {

    const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3()
    const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3()

    fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) {

      fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox)

      nodebBox.union(fragbBox)
    })

    return nodebBox
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns bounding box for aggregated fragments
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  async getComponentBoundingBox (model, dbId) {

    const fragIds = await Toolkit.getFragIds(
      model, dbId)

    const fragList = model.getFragmentList()

    return this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(
      fragIds, fragList)
  }

  getLeafComponentBoundingBox (model, dbId) {

    const fragIds = Toolkit.getLeafFragIds(
      model, dbId)

    const fragList = model.getFragmentList()

    return this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(
      fragIds, fragList)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates Raycaster object from the mouse pointer
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  pointerToRay (pointer) {

    const camera = this.viewer.navigation.getCamera()
    const pointerVector = new THREE.Vector3()
    const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
    const pointerDir = new THREE.Vector3()
    const domElement = this.viewer.canvas

    const rect = domElement.getBoundingClientRect()

    const x =  ((pointer.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1
    const y = -((pointer.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1

    if (camera.isPerspective) {

      pointerVector.set(x, y, 0.5)

      pointerVector.unproject(camera)

      rayCaster.set(camera.position,
        pointerVector.sub(
          camera.position).normalize())

    } else {

      pointerVector.set(x, y, -15)

      pointerVector.unproject(camera)

      pointerDir.set(0, 0, -1)

      rayCaster.set(pointerVector,
        pointerDir.transformDirection(
          camera.matrixWorld))
    }

    return rayCaster.ray
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  containsBox (planes, box) {

    const {min, max} = box

    const vertices = [
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, min.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, min.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, max.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, max.y, max.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, max.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, min.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(min.x, max.y, min.z),
      new THREE.Vector3(max.x, min.y, max.z)
    ]

    for (let vertex of vertices) {

      for (let plane of planes) {

        if (plane.distanceToPoint(vertex) < 0) {

          return false
        }
      }
    }

    return true
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  getCameraPlane () {

    const camera = this.viewer.navigation.getCamera()

    const normal = camera.target.clone().sub(
      camera.position).normalize()

    const pos = camera.position

    const dist =
      - normal.x * pos.x
      - normal.y * pos.y
      - normal.z * pos.z

    return new THREE.Plane (normal, dist)
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Runs the main logic of the select set:
  // computes a pyramid shape from the selection window
  // corners and determines enclosed meshes from the model
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  compute (pointer1, pointer2) {

    // build 4 rays to project the 4 corners
    // of the selection window

    const xMin = Math.min(pointer1.clientX, pointer2.clientX)
    const xMax = Math.max(pointer1.clientX, pointer2.clientX)

    const yMin = Math.min(pointer1.clientY, pointer2.clientY)
    const yMax = Math.max(pointer1.clientY, pointer2.clientY)

    const ray1 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMin,
      clientY: yMin
    })

    const ray2 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMax,
      clientY: yMin
    })

    const ray3 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMax,
      clientY: yMax
    })

    const ray4 = this.pointerToRay({
      clientX: xMin,
      clientY: yMax
    })

    // first we compute the top of the pyramid
    const top = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)

    top.add (ray1.origin)
    top.add (ray2.origin)
    top.add (ray3.origin)
    top.add (ray4.origin)

    top.multiplyScalar(0.25)

    // we use the bounding sphere to determine
    // the height of the pyramid
    const {center, radius} = this.boundingSphere

    // compute distance from pyramid top to center
    // of bounding sphere

    const dist = new THREE.Vector3(
      top.x - center.x,
      top.y - center.y,
      top.z - center.z)

    // compute height of the pyramid:
    // to make sure we go far enough,
    // we add the radius of the bounding sphere

    const height = radius + dist.length()

    // compute the length of the side edges

    const angle = ray1.direction.angleTo(
      ray2.direction)

    const length = height / Math.cos(angle * 0.5)

    // compute bottom vertices

    const v1 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray1.origin.x + ray1.direction.x * length,
      ray1.origin.y + ray1.direction.y * length,
      ray1.origin.z + ray1.direction.z * length)

    const v2 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray2.origin.x + ray2.direction.x * length,
      ray2.origin.y + ray2.direction.y * length,
      ray2.origin.z + ray2.direction.z * length)

    const v3 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray3.origin.x + ray3.direction.x * length,
      ray3.origin.y + ray3.direction.y * length,
      ray3.origin.z + ray3.direction.z * length)

    const v4 = new THREE.Vector3(
      ray4.origin.x + ray4.direction.x * length,
      ray4.origin.y + ray4.direction.y * length,
      ray4.origin.z + ray4.direction.z * length)

    // create planes

    const plane1 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane2 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane3 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane4 = new THREE.Plane()
    const plane5 = new THREE.Plane()

    plane1.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v1, v2)
    plane2.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v2, v3)
    plane3.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v3, v4)
    plane4.setFromCoplanarPoints(top, v4, v1)
    plane5.setFromCoplanarPoints( v3, v2, v1)

    const planes = [
      plane1, plane2,
      plane3, plane4,
      plane5, this.getCameraPlane()
    ]

    // filter all bbox which are contained inside
    // the pyramid defined by our planes

    const selectedBBoxInfo =
      this.boundingBoxInfo.filter((bboxInfo) => {

        return this.containsBox(planes, bboxInfo.bbox)
      })

    const dbIds = selectedBBoxInfo.map((bboxInfo) => {

      return bboxInfo.dbId
    })

    return dbIds
  }
}
```